# .NET development for pos pc

Tags: c#, .net, windows, embedded

I'm developing an application for a pos-pc running windows xp, this application is based on .NET framework 4 and use wpf for the UI.
I need to increase the performance of such application, I've read about ngen for generate native image but I don't understand very well how it works and how to use it.
Any tip, link, tutorial about ngen will be much appreciated.
I need to create a lightweight version of windows xp capable of running .NET framework 4 and use some COM object but i don't know what I can remove from the XP installer (using nLite).
I've tried Windows embedded 7 standard but the Intel gma driver are not compatible and i can't install it.

Thanks

Comment: There are, at least, two different (though related) questions in this post. I suggest you divide your question in two parts. The relation among them is too thin.

Comment: By "performance", do you mean startup performance or the actual speed of the application? What's slow about it?

Comment: @Baltasarq I think you're right, is better to split this question.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee Yes mainly the startup performance

Answer (score 0):

check this one: [Improving WPF applications startup time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx)

in short, `ngen` is an utility that compiles the `IL` code generated by Visual Studio build process into machine dependent code which does not require the `JIT` to compile IL anymore at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

How can ngen be relevant for a POS? DOnt getm e right, but this handles startup performance and POS get turned on once in the morning if at all (i.e. if they dont stay up overnight). If you ahve a WPF performacne issue may I suggest you fix those, and dont dabble with native image gneration?

Comment: This is a pos for a store, sometimes the employees needs to restart the pos and if there is a queue of clients this might be a problem

Comment: Hardly. DOnt get me wrong, but the 10 second difference wont make a difference. Plus ngen is NOT really something that has a hugh WPF side performance impact. I sugest you fix the wpf side perforamcne by checking and analyzing where it gets lost.

Comment: That is the idea. There is actually a WPF profiler out there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine have network access? Perhaps moving business logic from the client to a service on the network would improve the performance, so that the client becomes simply a UI shell for the service.